# Making this run while other views are in 'use'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, voice

Hello
Okay right I have a view called 'RecordViewController' this has the voice recorder function so once the user presses 'record', it records their voice, I have also created a 'back' button. But once that back button is tapped the voice recording also stops. I want it so once the user goes back, its still recording their voice.
Here is the code I used:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>


@interface RecordViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioRecorderDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIButton * btnStart;
    IBOutlet UIButton * btnPlay;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView * actSpinner;
    BOOL toggle;

    NSURL * recordedTmpFile;
    AVAudioRecorder * recorder;
    NSError * error;
    NSTimer *theTimer;
    IBOutlet UILabel *seconds;
    int mainInt;
    NSString *timeRemainingString;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView * actSpinner;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton * btnStart;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton * btnPlay;

- (IBAction) start_button_pressed;
- (IBAction) play_button_pressed;
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;
-(void)countUp;


@end

.m

#import "RecordViewController.h"


@implementation RecordViewController
@synthesize actSpinner, btnStart, btnPlay;



-(void)countUp {

    mainInt += 1;
    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", mainInt];

}

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender; {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}



/*
 // The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
 // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
 - (void)loadView {
 }
 */



// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Start the toggle in true mode.
    toggle = YES;
    btnPlay.hidden = YES;

    //Instanciate an instance of the AVAudioSession object.
    AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    //Setup the audioSession for playback and record. 
    //We could just use record and then switch it to playback leter, but
    //since we are going to do both lets set it up once.
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];
    //Activate the session
    [audioSession setActive:YES error: &error];

}



/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */

- (IBAction)  start_button_pressed{


    if(toggle)
    {
        toggle = NO;
        [actSpinner startAnimating];
        [btnStart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stoprecording.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        mainInt = 0;
        theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countUp) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


        btnPlay.enabled = toggle;
        btnPlay.hidden = !toggle;

        //Begin the recording session.
        //Error handling removed.  Please add to your own code.

        //Setup the dictionary object with all the recording settings that this 
        //Recording sessoin will use
        //Its not clear to me which of these are required and which are the bare minimum.
        //This is a good resource: http://www.totodotnet.net/tag/avaudiorecorder/
        NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        //Now that we have our settings we are going to instanciate an instance of our recorder instance.
        //Generate a temp file for use by the recording.
        //This sample was one I found online and seems to be a good choice for making a tmp file that
        //will not overwrite an existing one.
        //I know this is a mess of collapsed things into 1 call.  I can break it out if need be.
        recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f.%@", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0, @"caf"]]];
        NSLog(@"Using File called: %@",recordedTmpFile);
        //Setup the recorder to use this file and record to it.
        recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];
        //Use the recorder to start the recording.
        //Im not sure why we set the delegate to self yet.  
        //Found this in antother example, but Im fuzzy on this still.
        [recorder setDelegate:self];
        //We call this to start the recording process and initialize 
        //the subsstems so that when we actually say "record" it starts right away.
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        //Start the actual Recording
        [recorder record];
        //There is an optional method for doing the recording for a limited time see 
        //[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 10]

    }
    else
    {
        toggle = YES;
        [actSpinner stopAnimating];
        [btnStart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recordrecord.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnPlay.enabled = toggle;
        btnPlay.hidden = !toggle;
        [theTimer invalidate];

        NSLog(@"Using File called: %@",recordedTmpFile);
        //Stop the recorder.
        [recorder stop];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

-(IBAction) play_button_pressed{

    //The play button was pressed... 
    //Setup the AVAudioPlayer to play the file that we just recorded.
    AVAudioPlayer * avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile error:&error];
    [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [avPlayer play];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    //Clean up the temp file.
    NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fm removeItemAtPath:[recordedTmpFile path] error:&error];
    //Call the dealloc on the remaining objects.
    [recorder dealloc];
    recorder = nil;
    recordedTmpFile = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are in need of a shared object that your application can access during the recording process. Something along the lines of

```
@interface UserRecording : NSObject

+(UserRecording*)currentRecording;

@end
```

You will want to take into account all of the fun [threading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) principles as well as delegation and/or notifications if you would like to properly implement this.

Comment: UserRecording?
So I would have to create a new class for this?

Comment: I would recommend that. Once your start button is pressed you can start your audio session. Once recording has started currentRecording could return that instance until it has stopped. There would be some more methods like start/stop obviously.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do that, im still a little new to this

Comment: try out Mike's solution. The key is what ever object you are using to play the audio just needs to exist while all views relevant are visible. Say you have 3 controllers and controllers 2 and 3 should record audio but controller 3 has the buttons to record the audio. Controller 2 could create the audio object (not playing) then pass it to controller 3. Controller 3 then can start or stop the recording and when controller 3 is dismissed it will still play on 2. Once controller 2 is released it would not record on controller 1 because it was not designed to. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the AudioSession inside of the modal dialog, it will be dealloc'ed when you dismiss that modal dialog.  Try instantiating the AudioSession in the main VC, pass that into the modal VC and just start it there.

Comment: I guess I'd take a step back and ask what is the purpose of your modal dialog?  Is it to present buttons to the user?  In that case, I'd use a UIAlert, or a UIActionSheet, or maybe even UIButtons (toggle the .hidden property) and just do everything in whatever view controller is currently launching the modal dialog.

Comment: Hmm why would A UIAlert be needed, seeing as the recording will be still recording once the user has gone to another view, after they've pressed the record button. And what is the modal dialog, the recorderviewcontroller?

thanks

Comment: UIAlert is simply a convenient means for you to offer the user some choices (such as "start recording").  Since you are dismissing a modal VC in your back method, where are calling "presentModalViewController"?  THAT is the object that needs to create (and own) your AudioRecorder.